# What's the difference between io.sockets.emit and broadcast?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What's the difference between io.sockets.emit and socket.broadcast.emit? Is it only that broadcast emits to everyone BUT the socket that sends it?

It seems like they can be used interchangeably:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //these should do the same thing  
  io.sockets.emit('this', { receivers: 'everyone'});

  socket.broadcast.emit('this', { receivers: 'everyone but socket'}); //emits to everyone but socket
  socket.emit('this', { receivers: 'socket'}); //emits to socket
});
```

Comment: For 2021 searchers:  https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 204, accepted):

`io.sockets.emit` will send to all the clients

`socket.broadcast.emit` will send the message to all the other clients  except the newly created connection

[This Socket.IO Wiki post will help everyone reading this question:](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/How-do-I-send-a-response-to-all-clients-except-sender%3F)

The recent cheatsheet can also be viewed here:

https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet

Comment: well that took 3 hours of trouble shooting to figure out.

Comment: I can verify this is indeed the behaviour, but I cannot see any documentation for socket.broadcast nor socket.broadcast.emit in the Github docs nor on [the Socket.io website](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/). Am I missing something? (and the wiki has gone)

Comment: What's even "better" about this is that the example "chat" application makes almost exclusive use of `socket.broadcast.emit` while that API is never documented anywhere.

Comment: @Sobiaholic I still haven't encountered the obvious reason for not emitting the change to the current connection. Is it for when the client who triggered the event already had made an optimistic update in advance?

Comment: It's not "except the newly created connections", it should be "to all other clients except itself". You can have a newly created connection (a client joining the chat room) and you send a message using `socket.broadcast.emit` and they will receive it, but not you.

Comment: Thank you for this. I pulled out half my hair and gave up.

Answer (score 52):

`socket.broadcast.emit()` behaves similar to `io.sockets.emit`, but instead
of emitting to all connected sockets it will emit to all connected
socket except the one it is being called on. So in this case the socket
referenced by `socket` will not receive  the event.

Comment: one more update - as per Jayantha's answer and my own analysis it also DOESN'T emit to newly created connections i.e. the new client connections which were created after the 'socket' was created. This is an important and key difference !!

Comment: The "newly created connection" Jayantha refers to is the socket whose connection event is being handled and who would issue the broadcast. The point of broadcast is that it goes to every client except the 'broadcasting' socket -- the order that the client connections were established makes no difference.

Answer (score 11):

Scenario:1:- By the use of **io.sockets.emit** 
[Detailed Diagram:-io.sockets.emit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f52nC.jpg)

> Here Every Socket gets the Message including **Initiator**.

```
  // BY IO>SOCKETS>EMIT
   io.sockets.emit('MyChannelBroadcast',
               {
                 owner:"Anshu Ashish",
                 clientCount:clients,
                 message:"Welcome All"
               }
    );
```

Scenario:2:- By the use of **socket.broadcast.emit**
[Detailed Diagram:-socket.broadcast.emit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2ioe.jpg)

> Here Every Sockets are getting Message Except One i.e **Initiator**.

```
    // BY SOCKET>BROADCAST>EMIT
   socket.broadcast.emit('BroadCastExceptMe',{data:"HAVE A NICE DAY"});
```

Conclusion:- Now it will totally depends our business requirement that which one will be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

To make it quite simple, consider the following example:
there are 2 clients **client A**, **client B** and a **server**
we are using in response to certain event emitted by the client.

```
socket.brodcast.emit()
```

**client A** sends the event
In this case, the server will not send the event back to **client A** but it will send the events to all others connected sockets. So in this case only the **client B** will get the event response

```
io.emit()
```

client A sends the event, the server will send the reply event to all the connected sockets both **client A** and **client B**