# Socket.io not streaming to multiple connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to stream tweets to the client and everything works fine, as long as there is only one connection. If I am am streaming tweets in one tab of my browser and open the page up in a new tab, the first tab will stop receiving the new tweets and only the second tab will receive them.

Server code.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  var twitter = require('ntwitter'),
  util = require('util'),
  twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token_key: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
  });

 twit.stream('statuses/filter', {'locations':'-124.46, 24.31, -66.57, 49.23'}, 
    function(stream) {
       stream.on('data', function (data) {
         data.geo  ? socket.emit('twitter', data) : ''
    });
 });
```

Client code:

```
var socket = io.connect()

socket.on('twitter', function (data) {

    //Do really awesome things.

});
```

What am I doing wrong? It has to be simple. I can't imagine its this hard to support multiple connections.

Cheers

Comment: Unless you want each user to stream different tweets, it would probably be wiser not to do this in the connection handler, but instead set it up once and for all and do `io.sockets.emit` -- that should emit the messages to all currently connected sockets. In the connection handler, you would typically set up stuff that's unique to each socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `socket.emit` to `sockets.emit`:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  var twitter = require('ntwitter'),
  util = require('util'),
  twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token_key: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
  });

 twit.stream('statuses/filter', {'locations':'-124.46, 24.31, -66.57, 49.23'}, 
    function(stream) {
       stream.on('data', function (data) {
         data.geo  ? sockets.emit('twitter', data) : ''
    });
 });
```

Or if that doesn't work, adding `socket.broadcast.emit` in addition to `socket.emit` as shown below:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  var twitter = require('ntwitter'),
  util = require('util'),
  twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token_key: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
  });

 twit.stream('statuses/filter', {'locations':'-124.46, 24.31, -66.57, 49.23'}, 
    function(stream) {
       stream.on('data', function (data) {
         data.geo  ? socket.emit('twitter', data) : ''
         data.geo  ? socket.broadcast.emit('twitter', data) : ''
    });
 });
```

Comment: I did that but when I open a new tab and the new page doesn't work but all the previous tabs do. Like the new tab spawns the broadcast to all the other tabs at the cost of it not updating itself.

Comment: Well yes, `broadcast.emit` doesn't send it to the socket itself, just to all others. However, you could add an additional line of just `socket.emit` as well, which should fix that issue).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. That works. Is that pretty standard way to handle multiple connections or do I just have a fundamental misunderstanding of websockets and multiple connections?

Comment: Well, I actually haven't done too much with socket.io recently so a lot of what I learned needs a little refreshing when I get back to work with it, however, I have always had to use `broadcast` with `emit`, and `emit` it as well, so it seems like this is how Socket.IO works. I don't really have a clear understanding with sockets, so I may be off as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the documentation sure didn't provide much assistance. Many thanks!

Comment: You're looking for `io.sockets.emit`; see [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342681/whats-the-difference-between-io-sockets-emit-and-broadcast).

Comment: @BrandonTilley I couldn't remember whether or not `socket` was just a variable that you could set to whatever you wanted. However, that would make sense, so I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Don't forget to call `sockets` on `io` (or whatever variable you assign `require('socket.io').listen()` to), as `sockets` by itself is not defined.