# What is the purpose of `socket.broadcast.to(param)` in socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io

While I'm learning Node.js, I confronted an example to write a chat system.

Somewhere in the code there's following line:

```
socket.broadcast
    .to(message.room)
    .emit('message', theMessage);
```

I don't understand what the `to` function is doing. Also, I didn't find any clue at the client side code. What happens if the code has not `to(message.room)` part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between io.sockets.emit and broadcast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342681/whats-the-difference-between-io-sockets-emit-and-broadcast)

Comment: @laggingreflex my specific question is about the usage of `to` method. I already now the difference between `sockets.emti` and `broadcast`.

Comment: `.to` is for emitting to a room: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

socket.broadcast.to broadcasts to all sockets in the given room, except to the socket on which it was called.

For more details : http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#to(room:string):socket

Comment: I just don't understand the meaning of room. When you program with sockets in C++ there is no concept like room. Sockets are able to communicate only with messages.

Comment: By using rooms, you can also define arbitrary channels that sockets can join and leave. This provides a specific event to be emitted to the connected sockets of that room only. I have not used sockets with C++, so I cant help in that.