# socket.broadcast.to not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io for node platform with v2.0.3.

Below code working before a week

```
socket.broadcast.to(msg.receiverID).emit('new message', { "username": msg.username, "message": msg.message, "to": msg.to, "receiverName": msg.receiverName, "senderName": msg.senderName, "dateTime": data.created });
```

It's working and emit the message to a single receiverID.But now it doesn't work even i have not modified the previous code. But we have found one of the solution for this is to try the io object to emit the message as mentioned below:

```
io.to(msg.to).emit('new message', { "username": msg.username, "message": msg.message, "to": msg.to, "receiverName": msg.receiverName, "senderName": msg.senderName ,"dateTime":data.created});
```

Why this conflicts is socket.broadcast.to() is depricated or unused as of io.to().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between io.sockets.emit and broadcast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342681/whats-the-difference-between-io-sockets-emit-and-broadcast)

Comment: maybe u need a update of node version , and yes "io.to" will also work,
https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#

Answer (score 0):

`socket.broadcast.to(someRoomOrId).emit(...)` will send to all sockets in the room or matching the ID except `socket`.  So, if what you're seeing is that it isn't being sent to `socket`, then that's how this is supposed to work.

If you want to send to all matching sockets, then use:

```
io.to(someRoomOrId).emit(...)
```

instead.  The `socket.to()` version is specifically meant to exclude the `socket` object itself.  Here's some of the doc for `socket.to()`:

> Sets a modifier for a subsequent event emission that the event will only be broadcasted to clients that have joined the given room (the socket itself being excluded).